VSCode-Notebook "Interrupting the kernel . . . "
environment Win11, VS Code + Jupyter-Notebook + Python 3.12.4.
When running a simple code I have to interrupt the execution getting the message "Interrupting  the kernel 'Python 3.12.4'Do you want to restart the kernel instead?
Not always happen, I suspect it something wrong with (sometimes) the print instruction.
repeating the same code in .py in VSCode it works.
Bringing the .ipynb from VSCode to a proper Jupiter-Notebook, it works
